# Why does perl object instance overwrite each other

Tags: perl, class, oop, object, overwrite

I've written some Perl code which compose two classes inherent from a base one. I suppose it would print something like this

```
Mik: Meow! Meow!
Sat: Woof! Woof!
```

But it actually print this way:

```
Sat: Woof! Woof!
Sat: Woof! Woof!
```

,

```
package Animal;
sub new {

    my $obj = shift;
    my $name = shift;
    our %pkg = ( 'name' => $name );
    bless \%pkg, $obj;
    return \%pkg;
}

package Cat;
@ISA = ("Animal");

sub new {
    my $obj = shift;
    my $name = shift;
    my $self =  $obj->SUPER::new($name);
    return $self;
}

sub get_name {
    my $obj = shift;
    return $obj->{'name'};
}


sub talk {
    my $obj = shift;
    return "Meow! Meow!";
}

package Dog;
@ISA = ("Animal");

sub new {
    my $obj = shift;
    my $name = shift;
    my $self = $obj->SUPER::new( $name );
    return $self;
}

sub get_name {
    my $obj = shift;
    return $obj->{'name'};
}

sub talk {
    my $obj = shift;
    return "Woof! Woof!";
}

package Main;

my $cat = new Cat('Mike');
my $dog = new Dog('Sat');

print $cat->get_name() . ": " . $cat->talk() , "\n"; 
print $dog->get_name() . ": " . $dog->talk() , "\n";
```

But if I change the caller in this way, it prints what I suppose to be. So it is quite strange why the `$cat` object was overwritten after the `$dog` was instantiated?

```
package Main;

my $cat = new Cat('Mily');
print $cat->get_name() . ": " . $cat->talk() , "\n"; 

my $dog = new Dog('Sat');
print $dog->get_name() . ": " . $dog->talk() , "\n";
```

Answer (score 7):

Why do you bless into a global variable? Change your constructor to:

```
sub new {
    my $obj = shift;
    my $name = shift;
    my %pkg = ( 'name' => $name );
    bless \%pkg, $obj;
    return \%pkg;
}
```

Better yet, change it to something more idiomatic:

```
sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    my $name  = shift;
    my $self  = { name => $name };
    return bless $self, $class;
}
```

Moving on:

Why implement `new` and `get_name` in each kind of animal? Both methods can be inherited. While we're at it, we might as well get rid off the messing around with `@ISA`:

```
package Animal;
sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    my $name  = shift;
    my $self  = { name => $name };
    return bless $self, $class;
}

sub get_name {
    my $self = shift;
    return $self->{'name'};
}

package Cat;
use base qw/ Animal /;

sub talk {
    my $self = shift;
    return "Meow! Meow!";
}

package Dog;
use base qw/ Animal /;

sub talk {
    my $self = shift;
    return "Woof! Woof!";
}

package Main;

my $cat = Cat->new('Mike');
my $dog = Dog->new('Sat');

print $cat->get_name() . ": " . $cat->talk() , "\n"; 
print $dog->get_name() . ": " . $dog->talk() , "\n";
```

May I ask which tutorial or book you are following?

While the above is perfectly fine, you might as well do it the Modern Perl way:

```
package Animal;
use Moose;
has name => ( required => 1, is => 'rw', isa => 'Str' );

package Cat;
use Moose;
extends 'Animal';

has talk => ( default => "Meow! Meow!", is => 'ro' );

package Dog;
use Moose;
extends 'Animal';

has talk => ( default => "Woof! Woof!", is => 'ro' );

package Main;
my $cat = Cat->new( name => 'Mike');
my $dog = Dog->new( name => 'Sat');

print $cat->name . ": " . $cat->talk , "\n"; 
print $dog->name . ": " . $dog->talk , "\n";
```

Comment: Well, yes. Good OO design is always hard; the best the language can do is not get in your way. But I think that Moose makes it easier to get a feel for the correctness of your design. Take the example above. `talk` is used a a method, yet it is really only an attribute. Thus it should be a method in the base class that uses another attribute in the child classes. I find it harder to see stuff like this in the old fashioned form.

Comment: @innaM Thanks very much for your help. Let me explain something. 1. I really get confused that my Dog instance overwritten my Cat so that I'd like to check details in each class. I don't really mean to define get_name in each class. 2. I used to work with a lot of very old Unix machines so that I have to code in Perl 5.8 and must avoid to write anything newer than it. :-( . 3. Specifically for this question, it was a Python program I met somewhere in the Web, and I'd like to translate in into Perl one. But unfortunately slip on it.

Answer (score 4):

You have declared the variable to store the instance data using

```
our %pkg
```

This is an alias for a single data structure (`%Animal::pkg`), so all your objects are using the same hash. Change `our` to `my` in order to create a new hash each time.

---

It might be worth noting that "inside-out" objects in Perl can and do use a shared data structure in the package to store instance data, but there is an additional level of abstraction required to make that work, and I wouldn't recommend starting OO Perl with them, they are an acquired taste.

Answer (score 2):

In a nutshell: `our` declares package variables, so every time `our %pkg = (...)` is executed, you assign a new value to the same variable. As all `\%pkg` references point to the same var, all return values of `new` are the same object. A reference can only be blessed into one class, so the last one wins.

Just change the `our` to `my`, and it should work as expected.