# New perl object overwrites data of previous object

Tags: perl, class, oop, object, overwrite

When I create 2 separate Perl object instances the second one is overwriting the data of the first one. I am new to OO Perl so I think I am missing something basic in how I am handling the $self variable inside the class. Why does the data of $ptr2 object overwrite the data of $ptr1 object? Its probably an easy 1 minute answer from Perl experts but I have been beating my head over this. My actual application is supposed to grab a bunch of data from different sources and run some data analysis, so what I have below is a simplified version to show the problem at hand.

I did check [one other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17472783/why-does-perl-object-instance-overwrite-each-other) related to the same topic below but it seems to be different from my problem.

Below is what I have in the class:

```
package TestClass;

sub new {
  my ($object, $file) = @_;
  my $class = ref($object) || $object;
  my $self = { myfile => $file, };
  bless($self, $class);
  return($self);
}
# grabs key-val pairs from file
sub getFileData {
  my($self) = @_;
  open (FILE, "$self->{myfile}" ) or die "Cannot open\n";
  while (my $curline = <FILE>) {
    my @fields = split(/\s+/,$curline);
    $self{$fields[0]} = $fields[1];
  }
  close FILE;
}
# prints key-val pairs to stdout
sub printFileData {
  my($self) = @_;
  foreach my $key (keys %self) {
    print "$key -> $self{$key}\n";
  }
}
1;
```

Below is how I am calling the class objects:

```
use TestClass;

my $ptr1 = TestClass->new("test1.txt");
my $ptr2 = TestClass->new("test2.txt");

$ptr1->getFileData();
print "This is correct for test1.txt\n";
$ptr1->printFileData();

$ptr2->getFileData();

print "This is wrong for test1.txt, test2.txt overwrote test1.txt\n";
$ptr1->printFileData();
$ptr2->printFileData();
```

test1.txt and test2.txt have single lines 'VAL1 1' and 'VAL1 2' respectively.

Output of the script looks as follows:

```
This is correct for test1.txt
VAL1 -> 1
This is wrong for test1.txt, test2.txt overwrote test1.txt
VAL1 -> 2
VAL1 -> 2
```

Comment: `use strict; use warnings;` would have found those errors for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In TestClass.pm replace all instances of `$self{$key}` with `$self->{$key}` (lines 16 and 24), and `%self` with `%$self` (line 23).

Your output will look like this:

```
This is correct for test1.txt
myfile => test1.txt
VAL1 => 1
This is wrong for test1.txt, test2.txt overwrote test1.txt
myfile => test1.txt
VAL1 => 1
myfile => test2.txt
VAL1 => 2
```

On a side note, if you `use strict;` Perl will catch these sorts of errors for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I knew I was doing something silly like that. I suppose self is a reference to the hash and not the hash itself.

Comment: Also I tried 'use strict;' but that does not flag this particular problem.

Comment: I get this: `Global symbol "%self" requires explicit package name at cl.pl line 43.
Execution of cl.pl aborted due to compilation errors.`

Comment: You are right again. I had it in the calling script and not in the package .pm file. I fixed this and I see the same message. Thanks.